# Get Id and title from background events on dayClick

Tags: javascript, fullcalendar

```
$('#calendar').fullCalendar({
        header: 
        {
            left: 'prev,next today',
            center: 'title',
            right: 'agendaWeek,agendaDay'
        },
        events: [
                {
                    id: 'availableForMeeting',
                    start: '2015-02-11T10:00:00',
                    end: '2015-02-11T16:00:00',
                    rendering: 'background'
                },
                {
                    id: 'availableForMeeting',
                    start: '2015-02-13T10:00:00',
                    end: '2015-02-13T16:00:00',
                    rendering: 'background'
                }
        ]
        dayClick: 
        function(date, jsEvent, view) {
            if (jsEvent.target.classList.contains('fc-bgevent')) {
                //I can find out if it is a backround event.                
            }
        }
    });
```

I can find out if it is a backround event but how can I get the id of it?

Comment: Don't use `dayClick`. Use [`eventClick`](http://fullcalendar.io/docs/mouse/eventClick/)

Comment: I have tryed it but eventClick does not fire one backround event.

Answer (score 4):

Combine `dayClick` with the [`eventRender`](http://fullcalendar.io/docs/event_rendering/eventRender/) callback.

```
eventRender: function(event,element){
    if(event.rendering == "background"){
        element.data(event); //store the event data inside the element
    }
},
dayClick: function(date, jsEvent) {
    if (jsEvent.target.classList.contains('fc-bgevent')) {
        console.log($(jsEvent.target).data());
    }
},
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/slicedtoad/aLyy0q99/1/)